# How to fix ModuleNotFounError in Django?

Tags: django, deployment

I'm following a tutorial to deploy Django on Heroku and I've run into an error where after I have uploaded project to github, I can't run manage.py runserver. It sends an error message trace and one of the messages is module not found. Venv is activated, debug is set to false. 
Below is the stack trace errors. This is the guide I'm following for anyone curious. I am on Re-test and save changes to Github section. 
First 2 images are stack trace messages and last 3 images are my settings.py file.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can youshow me your settings.py file. Probably you are looking for a wrong file or a file at wrong path.

Comment: just posted settings file, just for those who wondering my app has already been included